# Sphinx で箇条書きの途中で改行したい

Tags: sphinx

現在Sphinxでドキュメントを作成しているのですが、以下のように箇条書きで改行を行い、行間なく次の文字列を表示したいです。

```
・文字列1
　文字列2
```

ラインブロックを使用して以下のようにしましたが、だめでした。

```
| * 文字列1
| 文字列2
```

どうすれば箇条書きで改行を行い、行間なく次の文字列を表示できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

箇条書きでなければ[行ブロック](https://docutils.sphinx-users.jp/docutils/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks)でできそうですが、箇条書き内では出来ない気がします。
reSTの文法上、任意の改行を入れられないためです。

カスタマイズ実装するつもりがあれば、カスタムroleを定義して、改行ノードを内部に持たせ、各種出力向けに改行ノードを適切にレンダリングする方法で出来るかもしれません。